# How to enable support for testng in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, testng

can anyone help me in enabling support in intellij for TestNG ? I'm using Intellij 13.0.1 Ultimate.

My project has a library for testng ( `Maven: org.testng:testng:6.8.5` ) containing `testng-6.8.5.jar`

If I hover over an `@Test` annotation I see: `[Maven: org.testng:testng:6.8.5] org.testng.annotations public @interface Test`

but there's no run test option when I right-click. In Run / Debug configurations there's no mention of testng. How to do this??

Comment: Do you have `TestNG-J` plugin enabled? Go to `Settings` (Ctrl+Alt+S) -> `Plugins`, make sure it's checked. If not, check it and restart IDEA

Comment: That does it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> > plugins >find **TestNG-J** enable